# Need to print last digit of string using lambda expression using java

Tags: java

I want to print the last digit from a string using a lambda expression. Using the below code I was able to print a complete number I but want to print the last digit

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestDTO> studs = new ArrayList<>();
        studs.add(new TestDTO("101", "Test 101"));
        studs.add(new TestDTO("102", "Test 102"));

        Map<String, TestDTO> mapDbCardDtl = studs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(TestDTO::getId, Function.identity()));

        Set<String> s = mapDbCardDtl.keySet();
        System.out.println("s: " + s.toString());
    }
```

Below is the DTO

```
public class TestDTO {
    String id;
    String name;

    public TestDTO(String id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Output from the above code:

```
s: [101, 102]
```

The expected output:

```
S : [1, 2]
```

Comment: do you want use same keys in map?

Comment: The ID is declared as `String` type, can the string be non-numeric or alpha-numeric?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in printing last number from the id, which is a number written as String, then:

```
 List<String> s = studs.stream()
            .map(dto->dto.getId())
            .map(id -> String.valueOf(id.charAt(id.length() - 1))) // take last character and cast to String
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to get. last digit from name value:

```
 final Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile(".*([0-9]+).*$");
 List<String> s = studs.stream()
            // find nunmber in name
            .map(dto -> numberPattern.matcher(dto.getName()))
            .filter(Matcher::matches)
            .map(matcher -> matcher.group(1))
             // find last digit
            .map(lastNumber ->String.valueOf(lastNumber.charAt(lastNumber.length()-1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

TIP:

If you wanted `mapDbCardDtl` to have last digit as the key, then you may fail, when more than one number ends with same digit. You will have to use overwrite merge function in toMap collector.

```
public static <T, K, U>
    Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                    Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                                    BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

Second solution would be using groupBy method, that will aggregate TestDTO into `Map<String,List< TestDTO >>`. Here the key is your digit and value : list of Dto's with this digit.

Comment: better use `String.valueOf()` instead of the empty string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your Student's object into the last digit of `id` then collect in a list.

```
List<String> lastDigits = 
         studs.stream()
              .map(s -> s.getId().substring(s.getId().length() - 1)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: If you collect in Set then it will contain only unique digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [Funcion#identity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) and expect to have different entity with modified values. One way is to convert `Map<String, TestDTO>` to `Map<String, String>` and use the following code:

```
Map<String, String> mapDbCardDtl = studs
                                      .stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(TestDTO::getId, 
                                      (testDto) -> String.valueOf(testDto.getId().charAt(testDto.getId().length() - 1))));

Set<String> s = mapDbCardDtl.keySet();
System.out.println("s: " + s.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to print the last character of the keys, add this line right before the `println` statement:

```java
s = s.stream().map(x -> x.substring(x.length() - 1)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you actually wanted the keys in the map to only be the last character, change the stream logic to:

```java
Map<String, TestDTO> mapDbCardDtl = studs.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.getId().substring(t.getId().length() - 1), Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have already done the most part of it, Just a little set manipulation was needed.
2. Look at the edit I made in the main method it will print your desire result.

   ```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestDTO> studs = new ArrayList<>();
        studs.add(new TestDTO("101", "Test 101"));
        studs.add(new TestDTO("102", "Test 102"));

        Map<String, TestDTO> mapDbCardDtl = studs.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(TestDTO::getId, Function.identity()));

        Set<String> s = mapDbCardDtl.keySet().stream()
                .map(number -> String.valueOf(number.charAt(number.length() - 1))) // take last character and cast to String
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());;
        System.out.println("s: " + s);
    }
   ```

Comment: "Want to print last digit from string using lamda expression"